# Connection times out on client's server

Tags: web-server, ftp, timeout

I keep getting a "Connection Timed Out" error when I try to FTP into my client's server.
I'm able to connect to all other FTP's I have, but not this one server.

The thing is, I've always been able to before and he said he hasn't changed anything and that he can still login with the same exact credentials I'm trying.

Anyway, my FTP client is in Passive Mode (although I've tried it in Active too to no avail), I've tried connecting to it through every type of server.

I can ping the domain in Command Prompt and it seems fine (returns pings), but when I try to FTP into it through even Command Prompt it times out.

I read some places that it might be my router, but I doubt that because I was connected just earlier and had my router on. Even so, I've reset it (and my modem, and my computer) a few times to no avail.

Any suggestions as to why I suddenly can't login to his server while he can?

Comment: 1) He can't restart the FTP service. He's not the server admin - just pays the guy and he seems to think it's my fault I can't connect.
2) I think the client is connecting to FTP on a different machine. For instance, client is in Location A, while the server is in Location B, and he's connecting.
3) landscapingportfolio.com
4) I've tried it and it keeps timing out too. Although it does return activity when I PING it.
5) ^

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can telnet to port 21 on that server, it's your FTP client. If you can't, either FTP isn't running on that server or it's a firewall issue.

To isolate it further, try telnetting to port 21 to the server from another network. If this works, you have port 21 blocked outgoing from your network (or he's specifically blocking you).

Comment: I don't think I have port 21 firewalled because I can connect to various other FTP's through it.